# Merge two similar click event into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is a recurrent problem in writing my javascript : I have the events :

```
$(document).on('click','.mi_piace_brick',function(){ 
   $this = $(this).children(),
   $that = $(this),
   i = s.get_current_step_id(),
   j = $that.attr('data-class'),
   counter = parseInt($('.like_counter_'+i+'_'+j).first().find('p').text());

   if($this.hasClass('liked')){
      $this.removeClass('liked');
   $('.like_counter_'+i+'_'+j).find('p').text(--counter);
   }
   else{
     $this.addClass('liked');
   $('.like_counter_'+i+'_'+j).find('p').text(++counter);
   }
  })
```

And

```
   $(document).on('click','.pref_brick',function(){ 
    $this = $(this).children(),
    $that = $(this),
    i = s.get_current_step_id(),
    j = $that.attr('data-class'),
    counter = parseInt($('.fav_counter_'+i+'_'+j).first().find('p').text());

        if($this.hasClass('preferito')){
        $this.removeClass('preferito');

        $('.fav_counter_'+i+'_'+j).find('p').text(--counter);
    }
    else{
        $this.addClass('preferito');
            $('.fav_counter_'+i+'_'+j).find('p').text(++counter);
        }
        })
```

As you can see, the two functions are basically really similar. I'm encountering really often in such situations. There's a way, in your opinion, to use only one binding to do the trick?

Comment: Can you just refactor out the body of the code into a separate function that takes parameters for the bits where the two function differ?

Answer (score 0):

Assign those elements a class that they will both share and attach a click event to that shared class. If there is a need to differentiate between the two, use data attributes for the element.

```
<input class="sharedClass" data-parameter="enabled" />

$(document).on('click', '.sharedClass', function(eventObject) {
    eventObject.preventDefault();
    if ($(eventObject.target).data('parameter') == 'enabled') {
        // your logic for "enabled" element
    }
});
```